# Timing decorator is raising "'NoneType' object is not callable" exception

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-decorators

I have i timing function and my main function. When i use only main function it runs fine, but when i use timing function as a decorator it raises an exception.

Timing function code:

```
def timing(function):
    import time
    t = time.time()
    function()
    t = time.time() - t
    print('Program has been running for {} seconds.'.format(t))
```

I use it like this:

```
@timing
def main():
    #some code
```

Comment: I changed print() to return and it started raising exception "'str' object is not callable"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The decorator needs to return the decorated function:

```
def timing(function):
  def wrapped():
    import time
    t = time.time()
    function()
    t = time.time() - t
    print('Program has been running for {} seconds.'.format(t))
  return wrapped

@timing
def main():
  # some code
```