# Python - Try/Resume

Tags: python

I am looking for a way to resume code from where it was after handling an exception. Specifically, I am experiencing an issue where I am trying to click different buttons, but sometimes a pop-up appears and interrupts the process. I cannot predict when the pop-up will occur, but whenever it does, I need to continue where I left off. The only way I can think of coding this is something like this:

```
try:
    click_button_1()
except:
    handle_pop_up()
    click_button_1()

try:
    click_button_2()
except:
    handle_pop_up()
    click_button_2()

try:
    click_button_3()
except:
    handle_pop_up()
    click_button_3()
```

Obviously, this is a very impractical way of coding this, since every single line would have to be in its own try/except block, but I can't seem to find anything better.

Edit: Don't worry, everybody, there will be specific exceptions in my use of this :) I just used except: for simplicity's sake.

Comment: You can use the retry decorator. Im typing up an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are several functions which have to handle the same kind of exception and deal with it the same way, I would write a decorator and decorate all of them:

```
def with_exception_handling(func):
    def handled_func(*a, **kw):
        try:
            func(*a, **kw)
        except Exception:
            handle_pop_up()
            func(*a, **kw)
```

And then decorate each of them:

```
@with_exception_handling
def click_button_1():
    ...

@with_exception_handling
def click_button_2():
    ...

@with_exception_handling
def click_button_3():
    ...
```

Later, just use them:

```
click_button_1()
click_button_2()
click_button_3()
```

#### EDIT: catching the exception many times

*Sam* asked in comments for a solution using a decorator, but handling multiple exceptions (as in [Alex's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40537762/389289)).

It is easy to do both:

```
def with_multiple_exception_handling(func):
    def handled_func(*a, **kw):
        while True:
            try:
                func(*a, **kw)
            except Exception:
                handle_pop_up()
            else:
                break
```

*Disclaimer:* Of course, this may or may not be desired, depending on the situation. Furthermore, I would rather not catch the generic `Exception`. Instead of that, the specific exception which is expected should be handled this way.

Comment: I really like this solution, as I feel like it keeps the code clean and easy to read. However, I also like that Alex's answer supports catching the same error multiple times. Is there a way to add that into this solution? I added a while loop around the try/except in with_exception_handling(), but it doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: @SamKrygsheld I added multiple exception handling code to my answer.

Comment: Thanks! Also, after testing, it seems that the exception handlers need to return the function, otherwise you get a Nonetype is not callable exception, see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25877767/timing-decorator-is-raising-nonetype-object-is-not-callable-exception

Answer (score 1):

```
for func in [click_button_1,
             click_button_2,
             click_button_3]:
    while True:
        try:
            func()
        except:  # you should really put a specific exception here
            handle_pop_up()
        else:
            break
```

The `while` loop is to ensure proper behaviour even if the problem happens many times.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the retry decorator.

```
from retrying import retry
def my_exception(exception):
    #should really catch particular exceptions, implement the next 
    #if isinstance(exception,yourexceptiontype)
    print "Saw an exception"

@retry(retry_on_exception=my_exception, hook=handle_pop_up)
def run():

     click_button_1()
     click_button_2() #and continue
```

Comment: `ImportError: No module named 'retrying'`

Comment: Run - pip install retrying

Comment: (1) It should be `hook=handle_pop_up` without the `()` (2) you missed `()` after `def run` (3) I get `TypeError: 'exceptions.Exception' object is not callable` after those fixes and `TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'hook'` if I remove the `Exception` argument (4) If I just use `@retry` this retries the whole function instead of individual lines as OP wants.

Comment: Hey , I fixed it, sorry for the typos

Comment: I am getting the same results as Alex Hall - unexpected keyword argument 'hook' and retrying the whole function.